# Is there a better way to model a parking lot with multiple entry and exit points?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, hashmap, object-oriented-analysis

## A parking lot is needed with the following requirements:

1. Approx 30 thousand parking slots.
2. Multiple entries and exit points (suppose 4 )
3. The ticket should be generated for the closest free slot from that entry point.

### The approach I thought:

Maintain min-heap for empty slots to give the closest slot at each entry. There will be a concurrency issue so a lock can be put on all the entry points. Problem is that it will be slow. and inefficient.

Is there any other better and easy data structure and approach to store the parking slots and allot them to the coming vehicles for the **primary 3 requirements** ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick the free slot with the best fitness score. [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) looks like a good data structure for this. When car needs a slot, take the first entry from the set, the class has a method for this. When the car leaves the slot, add the entry back to the set. You will need as many independent sets as you have the entrances, each having a different Comparator. You will need to add/remove entries from all sets, not just one relevant to the gate.

Simplest seems to define less and more by the fitness score in your custom Comparator. If the fitness score is the the same, then compare by the slot number, and then 0 (equals) is then for the same slot (slot number) only.

As lifts, entrances and parking slots do not move, you can compute the fitness scores in advance. I would store the pre-computed records as singletons in some array (or string to record map if the numbers are alphanumeric) so they can be fetched quickly as needed.